# Transitioning multiple html pages within one page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to create a single html page.  This single page should be split up into 4 equal sized divs and within these I would like to display other html pages.  For instance I could have:

```
Top left: google news
Top right: bbc news
Bottom left: reuters
Bottom right: twitter
```

I can do this quite easily using either `<iframe>` or `<object>` tags.  However I'd like to extend it so that I can have any number of possible underlying pages and they will appear within each div for a given period of time, before moving onto the next.

Are there any javascript animation libraries that might help with this?  Something along the lines of being able to parameterise the divs with a list of possible underlying pages and an interval to transition and then the library will handle the rest.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery and the UI framework/plugins would be perfect with this; you can use the [$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function to load the HTML resources, then append them to the DOM within the given DIV region you want to place it.  From there, you can use [JQuery UI](http://JQueryUI.com) or one of the many JQuery plugins to do the animation.  There are quite a few that would meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cVey9/) for you, take a look i'm not sure is that what you asking for.

The move of the elements is do it with css animate, in you'r page you must use `JQuery` transfomr -> translate or somthing like that